# How to iterate an array of objects and list key & value in pug

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, iteration, pug

I'm trying to dislay errors from an incomplete form. I have an array containing objects and would like to loop through the array and get the errors in it. However the list is empty.
The debugger shows that the errors variable contains

```
[
  {
    email: "Enter a valid email of format boy@example.com",
  },
  {
    username: "Enter a valid username",
  },
]
```

pug file

```
 .auth-head
     h2 Join Us Now.
     p Start by creating your account
       ul  
       each error in errors
         each val,key in error 
           li= val
```

How I pass it to the pug

```
  res.render("signup",{errors:req.flash('validationFailure')});
```

EDIT. I have edited the errors to be returned as a single object in the array @Barmar

new pug

```
.auth-head
   h2 Join Us Now.
   p Start by creating your account
   ul  
   each val,key in errors
     li= val
```

New errors object.

```
[
  {
    email: "Enter a valid email of format boy@example.com",
    username: "Enter a valid username",
  },
]
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have an array of objects with different keys rather than just a single object with all those keys?

Comment: Shouldn't it be  li= val ?

Comment: @Barmar I have tried that but it always come out blank

Comment: Of course if you do that you have to change the loops. Get rid of `each error in errors`, and just `each val, key in errors`.

Comment: let me edit the code cause I modified the loop as well @Barmar

Comment: There's no need for the array around the object in the second version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a standard [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop in an [unbuffered code block](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unbuffered-code) to iterate over an object's properties.

Using your initial data, you can achieve your desired result with this pug:

```
.auth-head
  h2 Join Us Now.
  p Start by creating your account
  ul  
    each error in errors
      - for (const property in error)
        li= error[property]
```

Using your modified data:

```
.auth-head
  h2 Join Us Now.
  p Start by creating your account
  ul  
    - for (const property in errors[0])
      li= errors[property]
```